# My app js file contains a large amount of extra script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm working with the SASS version of foundation and I'm working with app.js. When I installed Foundation through Gulp app.js already had a few lines of code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

import 'what-input';

// Foundation JS relies on a global varaible. In ES6, all imports are hoisted
// to the top of the file so if we used`import` to import Foundation,
// it would execute earlier than we have assigned the global variable.
// This is why we have to use CommonJS require() here since it doesn't
// have the hoisting behavior.
window.jQuery = $;
//require('foundation-sites');

// If you want to pick and choose which modules to include, comment out the above and uncomment
// the line below
import './lib/foundation-explicit-pieces';
```

In the compiled version of app.js in my dist folder this converts to around 14000 lines of code. I think it has embedded jquery seeing as I am working with jquery and I don't have to call a separate jquery file to get functionality. I'm not using a lot of javascript / jquery but the file in total comes to 487k. Is this correct? It seems quite big.

Comment: The classic case of including an entire library that does stuff you don't use. Some systems allow you to use tree shaking to only include what you need, but not if you just import the library. If possible, use standard JS over jQuery so you don't have to include it. But yeah, just the base library here is already pretty heavy apparently.

Comment: Oh god, I feel I've been on enough of a crash course already without having to learn about 'treeshaking'. The file isn't minified so hopefully that will reduce it seeing as the standard version of jquery is 250k and reduces to 80k when minified. I've also got slick slider js in there as well so I'm assuming that has upped the size.

Comment: I use Parcel.js for minimizing my code, and it supports tree shaking, so maybe have a peek into that - its minimal, no setup required. Maybe parcel can reduce what you include or need to include. Of course, just including the entirety of jQuery will never be tree shaken I guess. And not everything can be shaken like that, only ES modules. But its worth a try!

Comment: Thanks, it seems that jquery is packaged into my app js file by default by the line - import $ from 'jquery'; would you suggest to remove this and just link to jquery separately? I'll look into parcel.js as well thanks.

Comment: TBH, usually its best to link to a CDN version of jQuery anyweay, as people might already have that cached on their system, and only load it from your own library if necessary. However, I do not know if your dependencies are gonna like it.

Comment: Thanks I'll try the CDN.